# Preventing a specific default action

Tags: javascript, html, preventdefault

I am trying to create a simple web app. 
The app includes a simple Html interface:

```
<form>
  <label for="number">You are welcome to enter a Number:</label>
  <input type="number" id="number" min="1" max="20">

  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

There is a script attached to the Html, which runs whenever the button is clicked. To prevent the form from being sent and the page from being reloaded I used `preventDefault()`. It prevents that quite well, but it also prevents the `min` and `max` properties from taking place.

My questing is: Is there an option to prevent only one (or some) of the default actions of an event?

Comment: `min` and `max` aren't "actions". can you be more explicit about what you mean when you say "prevents the min and max properties from taking place"?

Comment: Please, show us the script since it may be more useful to help you.

Comment: it might help if you include some javascript so we can see exactly how your script is "attached" to the "html". i.e., is it an `OnSubmit` handler for the form, or an `OnClick` handler for the button itself?

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow — `<button>Submit</button>` **is** actually a submit button. The page you link to says so.

Comment: @Quentin you're right, that was an oversight on my part. i've edited that out of my comment.

Comment: please show us a script so we understand better what you want to achieve

Answer (score 1):

Events in the browser tend to form "chains". I.e., the button raises a "click" event, and the browser responds to that by performing validation, which raises its own events depending on the result, which can cause the browser to perform the submit action, which again raises its own event.

I believe what you've done is add an event listener to the button itself and prevented the "click" event that would have triggered form validation. As a side-effect, you also prevented the form from being submitted.

In other words, you only "prevented" one event -- but since they occur in a chain, you've broken the rest of the chain.

It sounds to me like what you want to do is preserve the browser's built-in form validation behavior (i.e. the part that enforces your `min` and `max` properties), but prevent the browser's built-in "submit" functionality (i.e. the part that causes the page to reload).

What you want to do instead is **add an event listener to the form's "submit" event**. This happens after validation, and you can "prevent" the event so that  the browser doesn't go through its normal submit action. That way, the browser still does form validation, and your code only runs if the validation passed.

```js
function onSubmit(event)
{
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('submit event prevented');
  // do other stuff here
  // this code only runs if form validation passed successfully
}

document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', onSubmit);
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <label for="number">You are welcome to enter a Number:</label>
  <input type="number" id="number" min="1" max="20">

  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and for the solution. It worked, thank you.

Comment: @אלחנןבעל-שם good to hear. if you don't mind clicking the green checkmark, that gives me some points and serves as a signal to future people who find this question in a google search that this answer is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what is believe what you want :

[See code here](https://jsfiddle.net/markosetech/wxebj8a5/59/)

```
var submitButton = document.querySelector('button');
submitButton.onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let data = document.querySelector('#number');

  let min = parseInt(data.getAttribute('min'));
  let max = parseInt(data.getAttribute('max'));
  let number = parseInt(data.value) || false;
  if (number > min &&  number < max) {
    alert("validation passed");
  }
}
```

Comment: there is some ambiguity in the original post, but i don't think this is what the author is looking for. i believe they're attempting to keep the browser's built-in form validation, but override the browser's built-in "submit" behavior.